# How do you define money type in F#

Tags: f#, types

Can you suggest a best way to define money type in F#?

Comment: Judging from the answers, your question needs clarifying. Are you talking about units of measure (e.g. for not confusing two different currencies), or about decimals and rounding problems?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Always, always, use System.Decimal for storing financial data!
(Unless you dont care about inaccuracy and rounding errors!)
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.decimal

Comment: So F# measures don't provide any additional benefits to financial applications?

Comment: Yes, but you still can define a decimal<USD> (or whatever currency measure you create)

Answer (score 5):

type money = int`<dollars>`?

Haven't even tried it to see... can you define arbitrary units, or does it only work with explicitly defined ones?

Obviously you'd probably want

type money = int`<thousandths_of_currency>`
(or tens of pennies, or whatever).

To be more accurate.

edited:

decimals take types so you can define money as:

```
[<Measure>]

type = pounds

type money = decimal<pounds>
```

which could ensure currencies aren't cross converted by accident, eg:

if

```
balance = decimal<pounds>
```

and

```
payment = decimal<dollars>

newbalance = balance + payment
```

will not compile, and you'll have to convert payment to `decimal<pounds>`

Comment: I don't get what is your suggestion :( F# allows to define arbitrary units.

Comment: F# allows you to define units of measure for a number type. So you can define a type length = float<metres> and the units will be preserved through calculations.
See: http://blogs.msdn.com/andrewkennedy/archive/tags/Units+of+Measure/default.aspx

Comment: But, joy of joys.. you can define units of measure onto decimals!
[<Measure>]
type = dollars

type money = decimal<dollars>

Comment: As of May 2009 CTP, you can apparently also apply units of measure to ints (though what help this would be for money, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 2):

[Luca Bolognese suggests](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2008/08/29/downloading-stock-prices-in-f-part-i-data-modeling.aspx) one defines their own Money type based off of float:

```
[<Measure>] type money
let money (f:float) = f * 1.<money>
```

Comment: I followed the link, and that's an example, not a suggestion. It depends on the application, but I believe for the large majority of applications the accepted answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

use a long, and store pennies (or tenths of a penny) in it.

You could use a class like Decimal, but that usually ends up [being quite slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366852/c-decimal-datatype-performance).

Comment: shouldn't correctness be more important than speed in this case?

Comment: how is using an integer type to store the smallest unit not accurate. Its not like using a double type.

Comment: Dangerous. Besides the high chance of error, you can later have problems when someone says the tax rate is $0.001 per unit.

Comment: I voted for this because I use a cent unit of measure and int. for my simple financial needs this works out great. I think the money type needs to be defined based on the requirements of the application. In my scenario, I can say with 99.9% confidence that I will never be using tenths of a cent

Answer (score 1):

F# now has built in support for **Measures and Units**.
According to the lead engineer for this feature, Kennedy it is aimed at **financial** apps among other solutions.

So I would look at that before defining my own money type in F#.

Werner