# I need assistance with summing up integers from collection in C#

Tags: c#

Hello I looking for solution how I can sum up all the decimal values from collection where each char letter has its own value.

For example, lets say that I am looking to get the result for the word CAR. 
Because each letter represents its value I am looking to sum up the result and this should give an appropriate output. In this case 8.5.  One more thing I am not looking for answer in LINQ.

```
Dictionary<char, double Letters = new Dictionary<char, double>(){
                {'A', 1.5}, {'C', 3.9}, {'R', 3.1}, 
            }; 

double result = CalculateScore("Car");
```

I would appreciate your help as I am new to C# and I have stuck with this task for while.

Comment: Your numbers are not integers. You need a `Dictionary<char, double>` (or decimal)

Comment: Also, let's see your attempt.

Comment: Avoiding the fact that those are **doubles** and not **int**, what did you try? I mean, okay, CalculateScore is a beautiful function name, but what did you try to accomplish this goal specifically? At least explain if you have elaborated any logic to solve the issue and weren't able to come up with a working code.

Comment: Loop over the letters, find the in the dictionary and sum them. Some code would be nice.

Comment: Is `a` also `1.5` or does it have its own value?

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to you to take another look at the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: `var sum = sequence.Sum(letter => Letters[letter]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's change the dictionary to `<char, double>` as 8.5 is certainly not an `int`, then let's implement `CalculateScore` (assuming that 'a' and 'A' is the same):

```
private static Dictionary<char, double> Letters = new Dictionary<char, double>()
{
   {'A', 1.5}, {'C', 3.9}, {'R', 3.1}, 
};

private static double CalculateScore(string word)
{
    double result = 0;
    foreach(var c in word)
    {
       var upperChar = char.ToUpperInvariant(c);
       if(Letters.ContainsKey(upperChar)
       {
          result += Letters[upperChar];
       }                      
    }

    return result;
}
```

And now we can use it :

```
var result = CalculateScore("Car");
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a double for this kind of calculation. But it is good enough

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabjan for your response. That is working like a dream.Steve can I ask why you would not use it for decimal calculations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329613/decimal-vs-double-speed and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when

Answer (score 1):

Without `Linq` https://dotnetfiddle.net/lhxpuf

```
Dictionary<char, decimal> Letters = new Dictionary<char, decimal>(){
    {'A', 1.5m}, {'C', 3.9m}, {'R', 3.1m}, 
};

decimal result = 0;
string input = "CAR";
foreach (char item in input)
{
    if (Letters.ContainsKey(char.ToUpper(item)))
    {
        result += Letters[item];
    }
}
```

---

With `Linq` https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wxzy09

```
Dictionary<char, decimal> Letters = new Dictionary<char, decimal>(){
    {'A', 1.5m}, {'C', 3.9m}, {'R', 3.1m}, 
};
string input = "CAR";
decimal result = input.Where(x => Letters.ContainsKey(x)).Sum(x => Letters[x]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply run through the characters of your word and get its value from the dictionary. When your current character however is lower-case you have to transform it to upper-case before.

```
double CalculateScore(string word)
{
    Dictionary<char, double> letters = new Dictionary<char, double>(){
            {'A', 1.5}, {'C', 3.9}, {'R', 3.1}, 
        }; 
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += letters[word[i].ToUpper()];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Just for the sake of completeness a Linq-solution which can be used by targeting .NET-framework 3.5 or greater and a `using` for `System.Linq`:

```
double CalculateScore(string word)
{
    Dictionary<char, double> letters = new Dictionary<char, double>(){
            {'A', 1.5}, {'C', 3.9}, {'R', 3.1}, 
        }; 
    return word.Sum(x => letters[x].ToUpper());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed `int` to `double` because you have non `int` values in your dictionary.

```
private double CalculateScore(Dictionary<char, double> letters, string word)
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    foreach (char part in word)
    {
        if(letters.ContainsKey(char.ToUpper(part)))
        {
            sum += letters[part];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

And call the method like

```
double sum = CalculateScrote(Letters, "Car");
```